# Rust std::fmt isn't working like expected

Tags: rust, format, println

I want to print the following:

```
->2     A1     B1     Test
```

but my code produces an different output:

```
println!("{:5}{}{:5}{:5}{}", 2, 'A', 1, "B1", "Test");
->     2A    1B1   Test
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you want to have five space between your items. How about using `"{}     {}{}     {}     {}"` as the format string? If this isn't your intention, please clarify your question.

Comment: If you want to [left-align the numbers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#fillalignment) within the width of 5, you can use `"{:<5}"`.

Comment: thank you Sven that works.